# javascript - simple arithmetic in creating dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm using jQuery with Django to do some stuff with tables.  I have the following javascript:

```
$("#pending_table").tablesorter({
    headers: {5 + {{somevariable}}: {sorter:false},6 + {{somevariable}}: {sorter:false}}
});
```

(I omitted a bunch of other options that are irrelevant)

The part that's causing trouble is the addition in the headers dictionary definition.  Looking at the source of the resulting webpage, I can see that {{somevariable}} converts properly to its value of 4, so it's not a Django-related issue.

In summary:  "5 + 4 : value" does not work, "9 : value" does work.

I'm assuming I'm getting the syntax of the javascript wrong somehow.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript object literals only allows literals as keys. In other words, you cannot have a calculated expression as a key. For example, this is unallowed:

```
headers = {
  (1 + 2): 4
}
```

That said, you can do this to circumvent that restriction:

```
headers = {};
headers[1 + 2] = 4;
```

In your case, it looks like you want to do something like this:

```
var headers = {};
headers[5 + someVar] = {sorter: false};
headers[6 + someVar] = {sorter: false};
$("#pending_table").tablesorter({    
  headers: headers   
});
```

Comment: Aren't you mistaking JSON strings with JavaScript object literals? JSON, that you are mentioning, is a data interchange format ([RFC here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627)), whereas the question is about JavaScript object literals.

Comment: I've always been confused about that one, since JSON stands for "Javascript Object Notation", so I assumed that it corresponded to the notation you use for declaring objects in Javascript. Is there a different acronym I should use? Anyway, I edited the answer.

Comment: I believe it would be hard to find acronym for that - this is just JavaScript's object's literal. If you are still confused, you can read the explanation of the differences between object literals in JavaScript and JSON notation here: [Mozilla Developer Network: JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).